# css web design on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, web, mobile-safari

i am new to web development.  terrible at math as well

i was wondering how does pixels translated from one screen size to the other on a webpage. Say for example, I specify 
    margin-left: 50px;

if i load this web page in my ipad webview, i measured it (using a ruler software, in px) it is indeed 50px
if i load this webpage in my desktop browser, it is indeed 50px
but when load this webpage in my iphone webview (which takes entire iphone screen), it is measured as 40px, not 50 as i specified.

1. sure iphone screen is smaller, it needs to do some scaling i guess..? is that right?
2. how is this conversion done? what is the process? is there some sort of formula?
3. what does this mean for designers? how do i know the right size i should assign, so the layout does NOT break on all screens?
4. i generally code on bigger screen first, then see how it runs on the smaller screen. is this the right approach.

i want a good and big answer for #2, can someone please help

Comment: I think you are just exagerating the fact that _new to web development. terrible at math as well_ Its not a rocket science. believe in yourself. As far as I know 1,4 are right. 3) If you are so particular about layout use jQuery Mobile for rendering your webpages(it renders the same for browsers & mobile browsers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest that you look into relative sizes...it will be relative to the device.  Check out any article about Responsive Web Design.  Hard pixel values are a no-no, if you get the percentages and relative sizes it generally fixes a lot of issues.  Now if you are new to web development you will want to do some learning before diving into responsive.  You can also probably do a little studying on media queries.  Just media query it for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have overwritten the margin of body? Some browser have different default values. If you look at the IE6 you will find something like this:

"IE 6 default margin on body is 15px (top and bottom) 10px (left and right)"

It is a good practise to have a css-file with some default values the reset the browser defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into jQuery Mobile and viewports. Basically you need to set everything by percentages not fixed width because each device has different screen size + you need to consider horizontal vs vertical view.

This viewport meta makes sure that the page is sized to 100% of screen width in any case:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

@media (max-width: 980px) {

@media (max-width: 979px) {

@media (min-width: 980px) {

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){

@media (max-width: 768px) {

@media (max-width: 767px) {

@media (max-width: 480px) {

**Taken from Joomla 3.0**